# Preventing magic numbers used in firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, magic-numbers

So I want to specify a time after which a post gets deleted. The time is 3 months, in my code I would define this as

```js
const THREE_MONTHS_IN_MS = 7889400000

export const TIME_AFTER_WHICH_USER_IS_DELETED = THREE_MONTHS_IN_MS
```

How can I define this in my database without resorting to the use of a magic number? Basically it looks like this right now:

```js
timeAfterWhichUserIsDeleted: 7889400000
```

Or as a direct screenshot of the database: https://gyazo.com/67abfdc329e1e36aae4e66b0da4b4f75

I would like to avoid this value in the database and instead have it be more readable.

Any tips or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `7889400000` is a UNIX timestamp, indicating a number of milliseconds since the epic. While you can store a value indicating the same moment in a different format, you'll want to make sure that the format you use still allows you to query the value.

A common format that is both readable and queryable it [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), and my current time in that format would be `2022-03-22 06:50:48`.

---

I noticed after re-reading your question that your `timeAfterWhichUserIsDeleted` is actually an interval and not a moment. If the interval is always going to be in months, you could store `countOfMonthsAfterWhichUserIsDeleted: 3` as a more readable form of the same intent. Just note that `3` is equally magic as `7889400000` and the main difference is that I've named the field more meaningfully.